# Is it possible to add an interaction to a component in Invision?

Tags: invision-studio

So far all I've figured out is that I can create a transparent rectangle over a button to create an interaction over a component. Is it possible to actually have an interaction on a component itself? The functions are grayed out when I attempt it.