# Can interactions be added to component elements in InVision Studio?

Tags: invision-studio

My header component contains different icons, like home, user profile, etc.

Is there a way to add interactions to these elements inside the component?

Comment: This is being tracked here, sadly they still haven't implemented a fix. https://support.invisionapp.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360018947211-Interaction-not-working-inside-component-element-

Comment: Dupe of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110823/is-it-possible-to-add-an-interaction-to-a-component-in-invision